# Trying to activate Netgear WNDA3100 N600 WiFi Dual Band Adapter

Tags: wireless, broadcom, netgear

I am very new to Ubuntu and am having trouble setting up my new wireless adapter. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I've added some more info about the adapter.

```
th0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this an older post but here goes.

You have to use the windows driver provider with the device. It's a .inf and a .sys file. Use ndisgtk [ndiswrapper gui] on the .inf file and in some cases need a reboot. Should be working then. In my case to get it to connect o my WAP2 security router I had to run "ps auxwww" which for whatever reason decided to make it play nice. If you have an open wifi router you're connecting to or something that uses WEP security you should be fine.